# Using predict.lm based on a model.matrix with different contrasts in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict, categorical-data

The aim is to predict new observations based on a multiple regression model.

The model includes two factors ("ec" with effect coding, "dc" with dummy coding) and a numeric variable ("num") plus an interaction term of "ec" and "num".

However, the predict.lm function based on new data fails.

```
# Dependent variable 

y <- rnorm(12, 50, 10)

# Independent variables

# Dummy coding

dc <- factor(x=c("Schlecht", "Gut", "Mittel", "Schlecht", "Gut", "Mittel", "Schlecht", "Gut", "Mittel", "Schlecht", "Gut", "Mittel"))

contrasts(dc) <- contr.treatment(3, 1)

# Effect coding

ec <- factor(x=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"))

contrasts(ec) <- contr.sum(4)

num <- rnorm(12, 10, 2)

# Design matrix

df <- data.frame(dc = dc, ec = ec, num = num)

lm_dm <- model.matrix(~ 1 + ec + dc * num, df)

lm <- lm(y ~ 0 + lm_dm)

# prediction

newdata <- data.frame(dc = c("Schlecht", "Gut", "Gut"), ec = c("C", "D", "B"), num = c(9, 8, 12))

predict.lm(lm, newdata)
```

How can I use the estimated model to conduct a new prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the model is estimated using an exterior matrix rather than with the `data` argument. Instead we may do

```
mod <- lm(y ~ 1 + ec + dc * num, data = df)
predict.lm(mod, newdata)
#        1        2        3 
# 24.19016 71.26768 59.50670
```

Sticking to not using this is complicated. For instance, the variables in your version of `mod` have names `lm_dmec1`, `lm_dmdc3`, which we would need to match. Further, in the process of supplying `lm_dm` as a whole we lose information that `ec` and `dc` are factors; for this reason we cannot use `dc` and `ec` as factors in your `newdata`; instead we must have dummy variables for *all* the levels. Thus, the best alternative seems to be to perform the prediction manually:

```
model.matrix(~ 1 + ec + dc * num, newdata) %*% coef(mod)
#       [,1]
# 1 57.08853
# 2 31.90847
# 3 47.81049
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was also my first idea. But I am explicitly searching for a way to predict related to an estimation based on an exterior matrix.